# How to pass argument values from a sub to an excel VBA shell command for remote execution?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to run a command (eventually a script) remotely on a linux server invoked locally from within a VBA macro on my windows machine. I tested the command outside of VBA from windows command prompt and it works, but I am not sure how to do the same from within the VBA macro since I need to pass argument values which are the selected values of combobox. I am also unable to redirect the output of Shell to some log file. I looked up few articles online and was able to come up with the following code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    comboBox1.List = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")
    comboBox2.List = Array("1", "2", "3", "4")
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call runCommand
    Unload Me
End Sub


Sub runCommand()
    Dim Ret_Val
    Dim Arg1 As String
    Dim Arg2 As String
    Dim command As String

    Arg1 = comboBox1.Value
    Arg2 = comboBox2.value

    command = "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" & " -v" & " " & "user@host" & " -pw" & " " & "testpw" & " " & "echo &Arg1,&Arg2" 

    Ret_Val = Shell(command & ">C:\logs\log.txt", 1)
    If Ret_Val = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error!", vbOKOnly
    End If
End Sub
```

Any idea what I am missing here please?

Comment: So the problem is, "it doesn't work". Are you getting any specific errors or anything more tangible? "here's my broken code, please fix it" isn't exactly how this site works...

Comment: You're passing the string "echo &Arg1,&Arg2" instead of substituting the values of Arg1 and Arg2

Comment: You need something more like: `command = "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe  -v user@host  -pw testpw echo " & Arg1 & " " & Arg2`  If that doesn't work, then provide an example of a known working command line of the type you're trying to generate.

Comment: @TimWilliams, many thanks, your solution worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the string "echo &Arg1,&Arg2" instead of substituting the values of `Arg1` and `Arg2`

You need something more like:

```
command = "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe -v user@host -pw testpw echo " & _
           Arg1 & " " & Arg2
```

If that doesn't work, then provide an example of a known working command line of the type you're trying to generate.